# Entity Framework code-first : how to add more props on model and update database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model, entity-framework-core

I have created a new ASP.NET Core 2.0 project with Visual Studio 2017. Currently I have a `Coach` model class:

```
public class Coach
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Methodology { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
        public int Rating { get; set; }

        //New property
        public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

I want to add a new property `Email` to the `Coach` class. I also want to create a `Review` class that is used to review a `Coach`. My model class `User` reviews coaches. However when I add new properties and new classes I get this message on startup of web app:

> A database operation failed while processing the request.
>
> SqlException: Invalid column name 'Email'.
>
> Applying existing migrations for ApplicationDbContext may resolve this issue. There are migrations for ApplicationDbContext that have not been applied to the database
>
> 00000000000000_CreateIdentitySchema
>   Apply Migrations
>
> In Visual Studio, you can use the Package Manager Console to apply pending migrations to the database:
>
> PM> Update-Database
>   Alternatively, you can apply pending migrations from a command prompt at your project directory:
>
> ```
> dotnet ef database update
> ```

Following the message I get does not work. The issue still remains. Can anyone point me in the right direction how to update the code and then update the database that is stored locally? How is the workflow supposed to be like when changing models code-first and wanting database to mirror that change?

Comment: run ' dotnet ef database update ' command in package manager console will resolve your issue

Comment: Have you tried use a partial class?

Comment: No I have not tried that! I will research it. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Generating & Running Migrations**

Code First Migrations has two primary commands that you need to run.

`Add-Migration` will scaffold the next migration based on changes you have made to your model since the last migration was created

`Update-Database` will apply any pending migrations to the database
We need to scaffold a migration to take care of the new `Email` property we have added. The `Add-Migration` command allows us to give these migrations a name, let’s just call ours `AddEmail`.

Run the `Add-Migration AddEmail` command in Package Manager Console

Run the `Update-Database` command in Package Manager Console

Comment: I did Add-Migration AddEmail and Update-Database but got this message:

    An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

    SqlException: Invalid column name 'Email'.
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.
    <ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__174_0(Task<SqlDataReader> 
    result)

Comment: If you don't have Migrations folder then first run the `Enable-Migrations` command in Package Manager Console and the run other two commands.